# Rxjs subscriptions do not work in IE 11 with Angular 10.1.1 and rxjs 6.6.3

Tags: rxjs, internet-explorer-11, angular10

After upgrading from Angular 10.0.1 to 10.1.1 IE 11 stopped working. Any try to subscribe (rxjs ^6.6.3) to even the simplest http request throws the error: "TypeError: Invalid calling object". Chrome works fine. Please help!

**service.ts**

```
test() {
    const apiHeader = new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .set('cache-control', 'no-cache');

    const url = decodeURIComponent(`https://.../api/test/test`);
    return this.http.get<any>(url);
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.test()
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log('ngOnInit', data)

      },
        err => {
          console.log('err', err)
        });
  }
```

**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "~10.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^10.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "10.1.1",
    "@angular/localize": "^10.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1001.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^14.10.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.14",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.2",
    "karma": "~5.2.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~9.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
```

**tsconfig.base.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**polyfills.ts**

```
import 'core-js';
import 'classlist.js';
import 'web-animations-js';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

**.browserslistrc**

```
last 1 Chrome version
last 1 Firefox version
last 2 Edge major versions
last 2 Safari major version
last 2 iOS major versions
Firefox ESR
not IE 9-10 # Angular support for IE 9-10 has been deprecated and will be removed as of Angular v11. To opt-in, remove the 'not' prefix on this line.
IE 11 # Angular supports IE 11 only as an opt-in. To opt-in, remove the 'not' prefix on this line.
```

Comment: I tested with the same version of Angular and same version of rxjs and [this usage sample](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs#installation-and-usage). It can work well in IE 11. Have you followed [the steps](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14455#issuecomment-493739768) to support Angular in IE 11? I edit `"target": "es5"` in **tsconfig.json**, why you edit it in **tsconfig.base.json**? Besides, I didn't change **polyfills.ts** and it only has `import 'zone.js/dist/zone';`.

Comment: I tried this usage sample too, it works fine. The problem raises when you subscribe to http api (I created "Hello World" one with .net web api). polyfills.ts originally had only zone, I added others during multiple tests. Anyway, I reverted my changes back to the previous state (Angular 10.0.1, RxJs 6.6.0, Typescript 3.9.6) and it works again.

Comment: Same issue here. Has anyone figured out how to get past this? I found that, by rolling zone.js back to 10.3, I could get it work with 10.1.1. This appears related to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/38669 and https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/38561

Comment: It seems the issue is related with **zone.js 0.11.1**. Reverting back to Angular 10.0.1 may also reverts back the zone.js version. You can try to use **zone.js 0.10.3** which shouldn't have this issue. You can also refer to [this link](https://github.com/JiaLiPassion/angular/commit/3ef440390379221e5f035afc3f64ba2ee2f779e2) about the detailed info of the cause of the issue.

Comment: Yes, zone.js 0.10.3 does work with other updates. Thanks Yu Zhou and  billdwhite! Hopefully they create a patch soon.